# Moq for Azure Function service call Unit Test does not return the Setup value

Tags: c#, azure, unit-testing, async-await, moq

I have a Service class (DataStore.cs) that retrieves values from an Azure Table. I am testing the method that uses the service class for the success case. the Mock of the Service class method does not return the expected value (it returns null)

The Method under test is

```
    public static class GetCellarBottleDetails
    {
        [FunctionName("GetCellarBottleDetails")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log, ExecutionContext context, IDataStore dataStore = null)
        {

            log.LogInformation("Begin GetCellarBottleDetails request");
            var stream = req.Body;
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var azureTaskString = await new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEndAsync();
            var key = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AzureTableKey>(azureTaskString);
            if (key == null)
            {
                log.LogError($"Failed to Retrieve Bottle Details for Azure Table Key provided: {azureTaskString}");
                return new StatusCodeResult(400);
            }

            log.LogInformation("GetCellarBottleDetails Api Request initiated");

            dataStore ??= new DataStore(log, context);
            var result = await dataStore.GetCellarBottleDetails(key);

            if (result != null && result.GetType() == typeof(BottleDetailModel))
                return new OkObjectResult(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
            log.LogError($"Failed to get bottle detail from DataStore.");
            return new StatusCodeResult(500);
        }
    }
```

The service class method signature is:

```
public async Task<BottleDetailModel> GetCellarBottleDetails(AzureTableKey BottleId)
```

My Mock and setup are:

```
var ds = TestHelpers.CreateMockDataStore();
ds.Setup(s => s.GetCellarBottleDetails(TestParams.TestExpectedAzureTableKeyForBottle))
              .Returns(Task.FromResult<BottleDetailModel>(TestParams.TestExpectedBottleDetailModel));
            //.ReturnsAsync(TestParams.TestExpectedBottleDetailModel);
```

I have tried both ".Returns" and ".ReturnsAsync" based on other stackoverflow answers and they both yield a result of null.

My call to the service is as follows:

```
var sut = await GetCellarBottleDetails.Run(
                TestHelpers.CreateMockRequest(TestParams.TestExpectedAzureTableKeyForBottle).Object,
                TestHelpers.CreateMockLogger().Object,
                TestHelpers.CreateMockExecutionContext().Object, ds.Object);
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AzureTableKey` is an object. However you create the body in the `CreateMockRequest` function the instance of the `AzureTableKey` is a different one from the one being created during deserialization of the object.

So they don't match with the setup.

Try with the `It.IsAny<AzureTableKey>()` to verify my claim.

```
 ds.Setup(s => s.GetCellarBottleDetails(It.IsAny<AzureTableKey>()))
              .Returns(Task.FromResult<BottleDetailModel>(TestParams.TestExpectedBottleDetailModel));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked great. Though I used  ".ReturnAsync" albeit both work.

Comment: They are doing the same thing, the one in a synchronous and the other in an asynchronous way.